# Prove that for $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^{n}}{2^n+1}$

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, complex-numbers

> Prove that for $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^{n}}{2^n+1}$,
>
> $$\lim_{z \to2} f(z) (2-z) = 2$$

**My approach :** 
I was thinking of applying Abel's limit theorem to compute the limit but since it is valid only for $z \to 1 $ I am totally clueless

I also tried by this approach:
$$ \lim_{\epsilon \to 0 } f(2-\epsilon)(\epsilon)= \sum_{0}^{\infty} \frac{(2-\epsilon)^n}{2^n +1}(\epsilon)$$

but again i am not sure of how to proceed.

Comment: Your power series has a convergence radius of 2. If you want to apply Abel’s theorem then just consider $f(z/2)$.

Comment: Thanks @MartinR for this direction I am working on it now

Comment: $$f(z) = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{2^n} - \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \biggl(\frac{1}{2^n} - \frac{1}{2^n+1}\biggr)z^n = \frac{2}{2-z} - \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{2^n(2^n+1)}\,.$$

Comment: @DanielFischer thanks , I am sorry if it sounds as a stupid doubt , as a next step, can I multiply by (z-2) and proceed for the right hand negative term as LucaMac has shown in his answer below or can I simply say that negative term vanishes when z->2 (after multiplication of (z-2) ?

Comment: Note that the last series has radius of convergence $> 2$ (it suffices that it converges absolutely for $\lvert z\rvert = 2$), so $$\lim_{z \to 2} \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{2^n(2^n+1)}$$ exists. Then the product of that with $(2-z)$ tends to $0$.

Comment: Great explanation , thanks once again !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just note that for any $z \in (-2,2)$, because of absolute convergence in $[-\frac{2+z}{2},\frac{2+z}{2}]$, we have $$f(z)(2-z) = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{2z^n}{2^n+1} - \sum\limits_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{z^{n+1}}{2^n+1} = 1 + \sum\limits_{n=0}^{+\infty} z^{n+1} \cdot \frac{2(2^n+1)-(2^{n+1}+1)}{(2^n+1)(2^{n+1}+1)} = 1 + \sum\limits_{n=0}^{+\infty} z^{n+1} \cdot \frac{1}{(2^n+1)(2^{n+1}+1)}$$ 
So, since this has radius $4$, it is continuous in $2$ (in $2^-$).

Thus $$\lim\limits_{z \to 2^-} f(z)(2-z) = 1 + \sum\limits_{n=0}^{+\infty} 2^{n+1} \cdot \frac{1}{(2^n+1)(2^{n+1}+1)} = 1 + 2\sum\limits_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{(2^n+1)} - \frac{1}{(2^{n+1}+1)}$$

Therefore the result is $2$.

Comment: Thanks , great solution ,I was confused a bit on the summation limits in your answer previous to edit but i think they are correct now again thanks a lot!